# Publish entire httprequest to RabbmitMQ queue for deferred processing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, rabbitmq, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a use case where I have to process certain WebAPI request in background. Currently I'm using RabbitMQ for queue service. I see most of the tutorial/sample provides publishing string data (to byte array) to queue.

Is it possible to publish both request QueryString and request body (could be text/binary data)?

It would be good to have suggestion on this in ASP.Net 6 C#.

Note: I'm OK to do little processing on the WebApi layer before publishing to queue.

Comment: You will have to serialize the data, e.g. as JSON or whatever format you prefer. There are many posts and tutorials available how to do that. What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: For my case, there may be a binary data (let's say a zip file) in the POST data, and the meta data will be in the Querystring. I'll defer the file processing and return the response to the caller immediately by writing the request data in Queue. I am wondering how to serialize both data.

Comment: Body is simply a byte array, so you can put what you want in it - you could send a header in the rabbitmq message which contains the length of your query, and join query and body in the message Body so you can deserialize properly afterwards.

Anyway, it's bad practice in rabbitmq to pass big messages in it - arbitrary being 10MB or so - technically, on latest versions your are limited to 512MB.

Instead, it's advised to use a blob store to save the value (memstore, redis, s3...), and use rabbitmq to reference the key in the blob store